# Which CSS properties comes in print and which not?

Tags: css, xhtml

Is there a list describing which CSS properties apply to print and which don't?

Answer (score 1):

Actually all css attributes would get printed, the only difference between your screen and the printed version is that your page would be wrapped in the paper medium you use (that is if you dont define a stylesheet with media='print' that handles this default wrapping behavior).

Comment: Actually, most browsers won't print background images or colours by default.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the properties apply to both screen and print media, though there are a handful of exceptions. If you look at the [CSS property list](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html), you'll see that most properties are marked "visual". Some are additionally marked as "interactive" (like `cursor`) which means these apply only to screen media. Some others are marked as "paged" (like `page-break-after`) and these apply only to print media.